# Socket.io message from server to client is incremented

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

Trying to build a simple chat app in React and Socket.io, using Node as the server. As the chat container I'm using the [react-chat-widget](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chat-widget), which has a "handleNewUserMessage" method to grab input from the user and display in chat container.

I connect to the socket just fine and am able to send message from client to server, but when I emit a return message from server to client, the emitted message is displayed incremented at client side... Meaning: first 'ping' sent to server returns 'pong' correctly, but when I send another 'ping', returned are two 'pongs'... Just like in the image below. Obviously new to React and can't figure it out...

[image]

server.js:

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`User connected with id ${socket.id}`);
    (socket.connected) && console.log(`The connection is active.`);
     
        socket.on('message', clientMessage => {
            console.log(clientMessage);
            socket.emit('message', 'pong');
        });
});

http.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('listening on 5000');
});
```

client:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Widget, addResponseMessage } from 'react-chat-widget';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

import 'react-chat-widget/lib/styles.css';
import '../Components/widget.css'

const socket = io.connect('server:port');

export default class ChatWidget extends Component {
    
    componentDidMount() {
        addResponseMessage('Welcome to this chat.');
    };

    handleNewUserMessage = (newMessage) => {
        if (socket.connected) {
            console.log(`Socket id: ${socket.id}`);
            socket.emit('message', newMessage);
            socket.on('message', receiveMessage => {
                console.log(receiveMessage);
                addResponseMessage(receiveMessage);
            });
        } else {
            addResponseMessage('User is not connected.');
        };
        console.log(`Message: ${newMessage}`);
    };
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Widget
                    handleNewUserMessage={this.handleNewUserMessage}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: My gues is you listen multiple times on the "message" event

Comment: Hi @Marc, do you mean 'message' event in "socket.on" of client's handleNewUserMessage?

Comment: It looks like so

Comment: Changed a code a bit, now with state. Each "handleNewUserMessage" has a setState to increment "count" and "srvMsg", which holds the value retrieved from the server. First ping is fine, then second ping triggers 2 consecutive setState events :| so:
1. ping - pong - count: 1, srvMsg: pong
2. ping - pong - count: 2, srvMsg: pong   AND immediately:
3. - pong - count: 3, srvMsg: pong (without "ping") 

??

Comment: by the way, I changed socket event names just to be sure there is no confusion/conflict there. Still the same - it continuously increments responses from the server and outputs previous count + 1...